# What is the seminal citation for the concept of a credible set

Tags: probability, references, posterior

I am writing a manuscript for a journal the readership of which is primarily not statisticians.

In the manuscript, I refer to the concept of a 90% credible set of posterior probabilities.

What is the seminal or "best" citation to use for citing that concept? Would it be a work from Bayes himself?